# Open untitled file in Document-based app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, document-based

I want my app to open new untitled document every time it starts. It worked in 10.6 but now I upgraded to 10.8 and when I close the window with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and then restart the application it won't open any windows.

How do I make it open a new window every time the app starts, regardless of how it exited previously?

I tried to return `YES` in both `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:` and `applicationOpenUntitledFile:` of the app delegate without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what changed since 10.6 but the issue is that the return value of `applicationOpenUntitledFile:` is suppose to be based on whether your manual open of a new window was successful.

In your implementation of `applicationOpenUntitledFile:` you should open a new window with an untitled document yourself. The documentation for this is under [`NSApplicationDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

Reasons why document based app won't open new untitled window:

Appdelegate method returns false

```
  func applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return false 
  }
```

Other reason might be this:
No restoration window found + some code presented other window -> no newDocument window will be created.
In this case call `NSDocumentController.shared.newDocument(self)`